# evaluating an integral over a circle |z|<1

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

The expression integral of $\frac{(z^2)}{ (z - 3)}+ \log(z + 2)$ is to be evaluated over a unit circle in the complex plane. I understand the fact that the integral is possible over all zeroes of the function $f(z)$ but I can't see any zero within the unit circle. I therefore seek guidance on how to proceed from here. I have tried using normal integration without considering residues as of Cauchy integrals. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The integral is zero as the function's analytic **on** the integration path (the canonical unit circle) *and* within the domain enclosed by it (the unit disk): this is just Cauchy's Theorem, no residues involved directly here.